# Marshalling an an unmanaged array of strings from a PInvoked OpenFileDialog (GetOpenFileName)

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, marshalling, openfiledialog

OpenFileDialog returns a pointer to memory containing a sequence of null-terminated strings, followed by final null to indicate the end of the array.

This is how I'm getting C# strings back from the unmanaged pointer, but I'm sure there must be a safer, more elegant way.

```
            IntPtr unmanagedPtr = // start of the array ...
            int offset = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr( unmanagedPtr.ToInt32() + offset );
                string name = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    break;

                // Hack!  (assumes 2 bytes per string character + terminal null)
                offset += name.Length * 2 + 2;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing looks pretty good - the only change I would make would be to use `Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(name)` instead of `name.Length * 2` (it's just more obvious what's going on).

Also, you might want to use `Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr)` if you are positive that your unmanaged data is Unicode, as it removes any ambiguity about your string encoding.